# How to customize styles in Ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I'm learning Ant design, and I don't know how can I customize the style in it. I have seen some ways on youtube and I want to know more. Like this picture, I customized the .ant-layout-header in Ant design by wrapping it with a div with the class header and css overriding it. But with this way, I have to inspect in the browser and find the class name of the component I want to customize.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq2Mi.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.